# How to split a string in shell

Tags: regex, string, bash, shell

I have a variable as

```
string="ABC400p2q4".
```

how can I separate `ABC400` and `p2q4`.
I need to separate it in two variables in such a way that as a result I get

```
echo $var1
ABC400
echo $var2
p2q4
```

In place of ABC there can be any alphabetic characters; in place of 400 there can be any other digits; but `p` and `q` are fixed and in place of 2 and 4 as well there can be any digit.

Comment: What shell? There are at least a few dozen.

Comment: What about other values; what are the criteria for splitting?  Is it the first 6 characters and last 4 characters (but what happens if the length isn't 10)?  Is it ABC plus 3 digits vs trailing material?  Is it 3 upper case letters, 3 digits, and the trailing material?  Is it split before the first 'p'? For your stated task: `var1=ABC400; var2=p2q4` does the job, no muss, no fuss.

Comment: too little information. is there any pattern/rule of your string?

Comment: In place of ABC there can be any albhabet, in place of 400 there can be any other digits bt p and q are fixed and in place of 2 and 3 as well there can be any digit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to split based on a regexp pattern as they are fixed length substrings. In pure `bash` you would do:

```
$ string="ABC400p2q4"

$ var1=${string:0:6}

$ var2=${string:6}

$ echo $var1
ABC400

$ echo $var2
p2q4
```

Answer (score 6):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and special `BASH_REMATCH` array (non fixed length) :

```
$ string='ABC400p2q4'
$ [[ $string =~ ^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)(.*) ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
ABC400
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
p2q4
```

Answer (score 3):

### Try doing this

using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) & [*process substitution*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (non fixed length) :

```
read var1 var2 < <(sed -r 's/^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/& /' <<< 'ABC400p2q4')
```

or this using a *here-string*

```
read var1 var2 <<< $(sed -r 's/^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/& /' <<< 'ABC400p2q4')
```

or with the short `sed substitution` version from [Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent)

```
's/([0-9])p/\1 p/'
```

### Note

`&` in the `sed` command stands for the matching left part of the *substitution* `s///`

### Output

```
$ echo $var1
ABC400
$ echo $var2
p2q4
```

Comment: +1 for the space idea. from his description, I think this works too? `sed -r 's/([0-9])p/\1 p/'`

Comment: Like in Perl, there's more that one way to do it =) Added your solution too

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by sudo_O is perfect if your strings stay single length. But, if that isn't the case, bash does provide you with [string regex matching builtins](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22664).

```
$ string="ABC400p2q4"

$ var1=$( expr match "$string" '\(.{6}\)' )

$ var2=$( expr match "$string" '.*\(.{4}\)' )
```

Replace the regex with whatever you actually need.