# Select a single character in an alphanumeric string in bash

Tags: regex, string, bash, awk, sed

I have an issue with string manipulation in bash. I have a list of names, each name being composed of two parts, chars and numbers: for example

```
abcdef01234
```

I want to cut the last character before the numeric part starts, in this case

```
f
```

I think there is a regular expression to help me with this but just can't figure it out. AWK/sed solutions are accepted too. Hope someone can help.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409947/how-to-split-a-string-in-shell)

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, please post sample Input_file and ecpected output sample with code tags into your post too, so that we could help you in same.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, it's my first post so I'm not so familiar with the way I need to format the question. My problem has been solved anyway, all the answers below seem to work. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash it can be done with *parameter expansion with substring removal* and *string indexes*, e.g.,

```
a=abcdef01234       # your string
tmp=${a%%[0-9]*}    # remove all numbers from right
echo ${tmp:(-1)}    # output last of remaining chars
```

Output: `f`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp like `[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z])[0-9]+`. If you know how to use `sed` is pretty easy.

Check https://regex101.com/r/XCkKM5/1

Answer (score 0):

The match will be the letter you want.

```
^\w+([a-zA-Z])\d+$
```

As a `sed` command (on OSX) this will be :

```
echo "abcdef12345" | sed -E "s#^[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z])[0-9]+\$#\1#"
```

Answer (score 0):

try following too once.

```
echo "abcdef01234" | awk '{match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+/);print substr($0,RLENGTH,1)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

*I have a list of names* I assume is a file, `file`. Using `grep`'s PCRE and (positive) lookahead:

```
$ grep -oP "[a-z](?=[^a-z])" file
f
```

It prints out the first (lowercase) letter followed by a non-(lowercase)-letter.